# A book for calculus

Tags: calculus

Can someone recommend a book for calculus that contains everything from the very basics to the most advance of concepts?
If there isn't a single book for that, then please recommend a list of books which can help me to understand calculus from the very basics.

(The purpose of learning calculus is purely for knowledge and not to pass some exam)

Comment: [See this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2609436/399334)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by Calculus. In case you're looking for introductory books on real analysis I really appreciated reading the "Analysis"-series from Amann & Escher.

Comment: @lush I would interpret it to mean a more methods-type textbook, not an analysis book. Focused more on the mathematical method rather than on rigour, and proving every result.

Comment: There is a good book:Thomas Calculus. It starts from basics to advanced. One topic it doesn't include is differential equations.

Comment: Anyway, Calculus by Spivak and Advanced Calculus by John.M.H. Olmsted fulfills your requirements!